# What is the right way to make an sketch's exported SVG responsive?

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

i'm learning to use svgs in my sites.

While making myself the code for the shapes it's easy to make it responsive, when i'm trying to use the same tecnique with a Sketch.app exported SVG it doesn't work. Anyone can tell me why?

Here is 2 examples:

first: shapes handcoded: [here](http://codepen.io/ciaoben/pen/gqcdL)

second: shapes created with sketch: [here](http://codepen.io/ciaoben/pen/Hiqor)

to achieve my goal i'm using this css code:

```
 .svg-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:1102px;
  padding-bottom: 31%; /** height/width **/
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sketch SVG has a hardcoded width and height:

```
<svg class="svg-content" width="1102px" height="348px"
```

To make it responsive, change both the width and height to `"100%"`.  Or you can remove them completely, which is the same thing because they default to 100%.

Comment: so stupid! spent hours scratching my head and the problem was so simple! ty very much!